# PyCharm - set "display as hex" in debugger as default

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Since PyCharm 2019.3 it is possible to view values as HEX in the debugger:

- int var in Variables view
- [right click]
- view as:

  - HEX
  - BIN
  - DEC

Is there a way to set HEX as default (not int)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet, please comment/vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39557

Answer (score 1):

There is workaround for this.

There is **Python type Renderers** in options under  **Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger**. There you can add new Renderer, select **int** in **type** field and enter `hex(self)` in **When rendering a node:** field.

It works as expected, at least in PyCharm 2023.1.2 (Pro).